# Does Scrapy crawl HTML that calls :hover to display additional information?

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm not sure if this is the correct place for this question.

Here's my question:

If I run scrapy, it can't see the email addresses in the page source. The page has email addresses that are visible only when you hover over a user with an email address .

When I run my spider, I get no emails. What am I doing wrong?

Thank You.

```
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
import re

class MailsSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'mails'
    allowed_domains = ['biorxiv.org']
    start_urls = ['https://www.biorxiv.org/content/10.1101/2022.02.28.482253v3']

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=r'Items/'), callback='parse_item', follow=True),
    )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        emals = re.findall(r'[\w\.]+@[\w\.]+',response.text)
        print(response.url)
        print(emails)
```

Comment: In short: simple 1 request - 1 response pages are now very rare. This page loads different js scripts that rewrite the original page. By default scrapy does not execute any JS found in the response page. You can either use a browser's dev tools to try and trace which scripts load the email info into the page and then query the endpoints that provide that email information; or search for scrapy extentions or other libraries that execute the scripts within pages.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're allowed to scrape email contacts from a public website,
as said, scrapy does not loads js scripts, you need a full render browser like  [Playwright](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/intro) to get the address.

I've wrote down a quick and dirty example on how it could work, you can start from here if you wish (after you've installed playwright of course)

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import Request, FormRequest
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright
from scrapy.http import HtmlResponse

class PhaseASpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "test"
    def start_requests(self):
    yield Request('https://www.biorxiv.org/content/10.1101/2022.02.28.482253v3', callback=self.parse_page)
        
    def parse_page(self,response):
        with sync_playwright() as p:
            browser = p.firefox.launch(headless=False)
            self.page = browser.new_page(). 
            url='https://www.biorxiv.org/content/10.1101/2022.02.28.482253v3'
            self.page.goto(url)
            self.page.wait_for_load_state("load")
            html_page=self.page.content()
            response_sel = HtmlResponse(url="my HTML string", body=html_page, encoding='utf-8')
            mails=response_sel.xpath('//a[contains(@href, "mailto")]/@href').extract()
            for mail in mails:
                print(mail.split('mailto:')[1])
```